# "Error in Contrasts" message in glm model after confirming that all Factor variables are longer than 2 unique values [R]:

Tags: r, glm

I am not sure why I am still receiving this message when running a base model with all variables in my dataset:

**My data, with anonymized variables:**

```
set.seed(1234)

#dput(df)
structure(list(outcome_1= structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    outcome_2= structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    outcome_3= structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    bl_ep = c(16, 92, 10, 40, 19, 1, 16, 10, 22, 28, 8, 11, 6, 
    47, 12, 1, 9, 20, 2, 14, 72, 28, 5, 16, 61, 12, 24, 22, 44, 
    44, 16, 36, 62, 10, 16, 10, 89, 22, 5, 38, 8, 11), bl_days = c(12, 
    28, 10, 25, 19, 1, 10, 9, 13, 28, 4, 11, 6, 20, 12, 1, 8, 
    16, 2, 12, 27, 28, 5, 13, 24, 10, 18, 18, 16, 16, 10, 28, 
    22, 5, 15, 8, 28, 15, 5, 22, 7, 11), score_1 = c(11, 
    19, 17, 17, 12, 14, 8, 12, 14, 15, 14, 13, 12, 14, 15, 5, 
    11, 14, 14, 13, 16, 11, 11, 14, 20, 14, 12, 11, 17, 15, 14, 
    18, 15, 14, 12, 10, 17, 16, 11, 13, 18, 17), score_2 = c(1.1, 
    1.6, 1.6, 2.8, 1.9, 3.3, 4, 3.8, 1.8, 1.4, 2, 3.55, 1.6, 
    1.8, 2.4, 3.7, 1.4, 2.9, 3.55, 2.5, 1.6, 3.2, 3.5, 2.4, 3.1, 
    2.3, 3.8, 3.9, 1.1, 1.7, 2.3, 1.5, 1.9, 3.3, 3, 2.9, 1.6, 
    3.1, 3.7, 2.8, 1.2, 1.9), score_3 = c(1, 
    1.22222222222222, 1.11111111111111, 1.88888888888889, 1.44444444444444, 
    1.44444444444444, 3.22222222222222, 2.77777777777778, 1.11111111111111, 
    1, 1, 2.83333333333333, 1.22222222222222, 1.875, 1.55555555555556, 
    2.66666666666667, 1, 2.25, 1.72222222222222, 2.05555555555556, 
    1.22222222222222, 2, 2, 1.77777777777778, 1.33333333333333, 
    1.11111111111111, 2.5, 2.55555555555556, 1, 1.22222222222222, 
    1.77777777777778, 1.22222222222222, 2.44444444444444, 1.55555555555556, 
    1.77777777777778, 1.66666666666667, 1.11111111111111, 2.33333333333333, 
    2.88888888888889, 1.55555555555556, 1, 1.25), score_4 = c(1.31428571428571, 
    1.37142857142857, 1.08571428571429, 1.83809523809524, 1.37142857142857, 
    1.8952380952381, 4, 3.88571428571429, 3.02857142857143, 2.12222222222222, 
    1.43333333333333, 3.39047619047619, 1.74285714285714, 1.67619047619048, 
    2.02857142857143, 3.48571428571429, 1.24761904761905, 3.73333333333333, 
    3.08571428571429, 2.56666666666667, 1.74285714285714, 2.6952380952381, 
    3.45714285714286, 2.27619047619048, 1.9047619047619, 2.62857142857143, 
    3.74285714285714, 3.74285714285714, 1.24761904761905, 1.39047619047619, 
    1.83809523809524, 2.74285714285714, 4, 1.77142857142857, 
    3.42857142857143, 3.2, 1.65714285714286, 2.55238095238095, 
    2.38095238095238, 2.40952380952381, 2.07619047619048, 2.56666666666667
    ), score_5 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1.33333333333333, 
    1, 3.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 1.66666666666667, 
    1.66666666666667, 2, 2.5, 1.66666666666667, 1, 1.33333333333333, 
    3, 1, 1.66666666666667, 2.16666666666667, 2.16666666666667, 
    1.33333333333333, 2.66666666666667, 3, 2.66666666666667, 
    1.33333333333333, 2.66666666666667, 3, 1.33333333333333, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.33333333333333, 3, 3.66666666666667, 1.66666666666667, 
    1.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 1.66666666666667, 2, 
    2), sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), age = c(64, 
    66, 51, 69, 60, 65, 65, 69, 50, 78, 75, 78, 35, 77, 69, 48, 
    65, 72, 60, 64, 78, 71, 58, 55, 55, 57, 81, 76, 56, 71, 56, 
    73, 69, 51, 43, 77, 31, 64, 69, 63, 38, 71), childbirth = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("N", 
    "Y"), class = "factor"), x1= c(3, 2, 2, NA, 
    3, 2, 3, NA, 3, 3, 2, 2, NA, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 
    NA, 2, 3, NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, NA, 2, 2, 1, 
    3), x2= c(0, 0, 0, NA, 1, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, NA, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0), x3= structure(c(4L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, NA, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
    1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("N", 
    "NA", "UNK", "Y"), class = "factor"), x4= structure(c(4L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
    3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, NA, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("N", 
    "NA", "UNK", "Y"), class = "factor"), x5= structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("N", 
    "Y"), class = "factor"), x6= structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
    x7= structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, NA, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("N", "NA", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
    x8= structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), x9= structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("N", 
    "Y"), class = "factor"), x10= structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
    x11= structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
    x12= structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
    x13= structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
    x14= c(41, 7, 8, 9, 7, 2, 1, 5, 9, 6, 6, 8, 
    14, 2, 4, NA, 11, 9, 31, 13, 8, 2, 11, 20, 8, 7, 6, 8, 2, 
    12, 32, 1, 2, 38, 10, 17, 5, 28, 31, 10, 3, 6), x15= structure(c(3L, 
    4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("IATRO", 
    "IDIO", "OBST", "OBST/IDIO", "TRAUM"), class = "factor"), 
    x16= structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
    x17= structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
    x18= c(31.8, 20, 30.9, 23.3, 22.5, 23.1, 23.6, 25.9, 22.8, 
    25.2, 30.2, 23.4, 22.2, 29, 24.8, 32.7, 20.8, 28.5, 24.6, 
    23, 23.4, 21.1, 24.9, 18, 21.7, 27.6, 27, 29, 32.9, 26, 29.3, 
    27.1, 22.7, 19.7, 25, 22.3, 21.3, 17.5, 20.9, 20.1, 25.1, 
    22.1), x19= structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    x20 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("NO", "YES"), class = "factor"), 
    x21= structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("NO", "YES"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-42L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
 logit1 <-glm(outcome_1~., data = df, family = "binomial")
```

Which yielded the classic error message for a logit model:

```
#Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
#  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

***Ok, so*** I went to double check that all factor variables indeed have more than 1 unique value, and can verify:

```
sapply(lapply(df, unique), length)
```

returned all variables showing 2 or more unique values. Still same error message when I ran the model again.

I even attempted to run one solution I found online:

```
values_count <- sapply(lapply(df, unique), length)

logit1 <-
  lm(outcome_1~ ., df[ , values_count > 1])
```

***What's going on? Am I blind in seeing some variable that is secretly saying it has more than one unique value and does not?***

Thank you!

Comment: the model you are trying to fit has 33 variables and 42 observations

Comment: @rawr: error still occurs when I run with 3 variables. This is supposed to be a "full" model as an exploratory analysis.

Answer (score 1):

The regression works on the supplied data for simple models, such as

```
logit1 <-glm(outcome_1~ sex + age, data = df, family = "binomial")
```

It's a small data set with lots of variables, the computer is not going to be able to pull out the meaningful relationships even if they are there.  Start with some exploratory data plots, and think about how the (biological) relationship between your outcomes and other variables in order to come up with hypotheses you can test with you data. Realistically, which measurements do you think actually affect patient outcomes?

Comment: Thanks for this!
I appreciate the response, but it kind of points out what I already am looking for - this is supposed to be exploratory in nature, not confirmatory.